# How we can add Html Tags in Titanium iOS label

Tags: html, ios, titanium

I'm working on Appcelerator studio .i want to add html tags in label text.how i can add this in label.

```
var labThesisDetail = Titanium.UI.WebView({
        text : "<p><strong>Master Of Science in Land Resource Management</strong></p> <p> </p>",
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        right : 20,
        top : 20,
        editable : false,
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        left : 20,
        color : "black",
        font : {
            fontSize : 13,
            //fontFamily : "Signika-Regular",
            fontWeight : 'normal'
        }
    });
    viewCourseSummary.add(labThesisDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Android` only has an `html` property to do this : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-html

I you want crossplatform code, you can use this module : http://gitt.io/component/ti.styledlabel (it's more lighter than using a `WebView`)

```
var StyledLabel = require('ti.styledlabel');
var label = StyledLabel.createLabel({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE || 'auto',
    top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5,
    html: '<center>Loading, please wait.</center>'
});
```